# Code Coverage resulting in following issue

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, eclemma

I am trying to perform Code Coverage analysis for my JUnit Test Classes but it is throwing following error :
I have created two separate folders (main and test).
I am not able to create a clean build.

```
Class not found com.automationanywhere.botcommand.oexcelonline.commands.range.DeleteRangeTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.automationanywhere.botcommand.oexcelonline.commands.range.DeleteRangeTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Class not found com.automationanywhere.botcommand.oexcelonline.commands.workbook.OpenWorkbookTest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple and absolute alternative who are trying gradle and want to check up their code Coverage.

Before following steps mentioned below,
just add few dependencies within your build.gradle file:

```
 apply plugin: "jacoco"

 jacoco {
 toolVersion = "0.8.4"
 reportsDir = file("$buildDir/")
  }

 tasks.withType(Test) { task -> jacoco { destinationFile = 
  file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco/${task.name}.exec") } }
 jacocoTestReport {
  reports {
    html.enabled true
    xml.enabled true
    csv.enabled true
    html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
}}
```

follow these steps:

1. Clean up ur gradle:
      gradle clean
2. run your Test file:
      gradle test --info --tests .Test.java
3. now to generate report for your code coverage :
      gradle jacocoTestReport

that's all you need.
now go to build->jacocoHTML->index.html

Enjoy..

Answer (score 0):

Try doing maven update using Alt+F5 in eclipse and then run below command:

mvn clean install -DskipTests

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Shirsh Senha I have build this project in gradle. So can you suggest me for the same?